# The problem with SQLITE in the telegram bot on aiogram 3.0

Tags: sqlite, aiogram

I am trying to implement the usual output of information from the database in the telegram bot. If I do it through a callback, it doesn't work. If I do it through the command, everything works. What do you advise me to do?

Here I use the output via the /profile command

```
async def profile_info(message, reply, user_id):
userid = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE tg_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
if userid:
    await message.answer(' Profile\n\n'
                                     f'Card: {userid[2]}\n'
                                     'Deals: 0', reply_markup=reply)
db.commit()
```

- 

```
@cmds_router.message(F.text, Command('profile'))
async def profileGet(message: Message):
    await profile_info(message, backkb.profile_back_kb, message.from_user.id)
```

But if I make this conclusion through the callback, then it just doesn't work

```
async def profile_info(callback, reply, user_id):
userid = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE tg_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
if userid:
    await callback.message.answer(' Profile\n\n'
                                     f'Card: {userid[2]}\n'
                                     'Deals: 0', reply_markup=reply)
db.commit()
```

- 

```
@router_main_handler.callback_query(F.data == 'profile_menu_cb')
async def profile_menu_cb(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await profile_info(callback, backkb.profile_back_kb, callback.message.from_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to answer a callback, so telegram understands that you are handling this callback.

So, the code could look like this:

```py
async def profile_info(callback, reply, user_id):
    await callback.answer()
    userid = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM 
    accounts WHERE tg_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
    if userid:
        await callback.message.answer(' Profile\n\n'
                                      f'Card: {userid[2]}\n'
                                     'Deals: 0', reply_markup=reply)
    db.commit()
```